# How to return only the child models of a one to many relationship - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I was hoping I could get some assistance here.

Here is my model structure:

```
Property 1
--Image 1
--Image 2
Property 2
--Image 3
--Image 4
```

What I'm trying to do is retrieve all Image models.

This is what I have tried:

```
$properties = Auth::user()
    ->landlord_profile_auto
    ->properties()
    ->with('images')
    ->get();

dd($properties->images);

Property [images] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Thanks a lot

**EDIT:**

Here is the dump of a property:

```
>>> Property::whereHas('images')->with('images')->first()
=> App\Models\Property {#3064
 id: 3,
 created_at: "2019-01-23 17:31:34",
 updated_at: "2019-01-23 20:22:45",
 address_line_1: "ABC",
 address_line_2: "ABC",
 unit: "calculateStorageUsage",
 city: "ABC",
 postal_code: "calculateStorageUsage",
 url_slug: null,
 is_draft: 0,
 is_refurb: 0,
 purchased_date: "2019-01-23",
 bedrooms: 3,
 max_tenants: null,
 rent_amount: "589595.00",
 currency_id: 252,
 country_id: 491,
 rent_frequency_id: 7,
 property_type_id: null,
 featured_image_id: 4,
 landlord_profile_id: 6,
 images: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3059
   all: [
     App\Models\Image {#3078
       id: 4,
       created_at: "2019-01-23 20:22:42",
       updated_at: "2019-01-23 20:22:42",
       name: null,
       caption: null,
       path: "property_images/Ba1XYIB394xLsH4365391beAZ.jpg",
       size_kb: 849.85,
       imageable_type: "App\Models\Property",
       imageable_id: 3,
     },
     App\Models\Image {#3077
       id: 5,
       created_at: "2019-01-23 20:22:45",
       updated_at: "2019-01-23 20:22:45",
       name: null,
       caption: null,
       path: "property_images/An3bgmKJzMcPuZyYizp9Lm6dj.jpg",
       size_kb: 849.85,
       imageable_type: "App\Models\Property",
       imageable_id: 3,
     },
   ],
 },
}
```

Properties has a one to many relationship to images. Images is a polymorphic table.

Comment: Can you please dump your `$properties` and show here.

Comment: It's an instance of type `collection` You need the underlying `model` to access its properties. For example you can loop the collection: `foreach($properties as $property){$property->images//here you have it`

Comment: @user3647971 Thanks a lot. I didn't think about the fact that it's a collection.

Comment: @NikhilVaghela Thanks a lot, done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@foreach($properties->images as $image)
{
 // here you can acess each image
}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is weird but I'm still getting an error. "Property [images] does not exist on this collection instance.".

foreach($properties->images as $image){
            echo $image;
        }

Comment: Can you show me your models? Maybe there is something wrong with it